# How does Spider-Man use his magnetic webbing in a vacuum?

Tags: comics, marvel, spider-man

Spider-Man's webbing requires air to become adhesive, as discussed [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10618/3804). Yet in the latest Spider-Man comic he manages to use his magnetic webbing in a vacuum. How much 'air' does he need? Was the vacuum from opening to space not 'hard'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess here is two-fold:

- Magnetic webbing provides a force by which to assist in the propelling (rather pulling) of webs to an intended target, and
- The targets on which he uses his magnetic webbing (octobot zombies) contain magnetic material.

From [Food for Thought: The Empty Calories of *Amazing Spider-Man* #681](https://www.popmatters.com/pm/review/155811-food-for-thought-the-empty-calories-of-amazing-spider-man-681), Spider-Man says:

> I switched to my magnetic web cartridges. If I aim it right, it should attach to the octobots on all the crew.

[image: Spider-Man's magnetic web cartridges]

Comment: But that avoids the fact the webbing doesn't work without air...

Comment: @Pureferret - The adhesive nature of webbing becomes unimportant when it's replaced with another compelling force, like a strong magnetic one. Obviously won't help against non-magnetic materials though.

Answer (score -1):

For a while Spider-Man had cosmic powers.  This came from an alien symbiote that replaced his red suit.  (The suit that became Venom after it was rejected but that is an answer to a different question)

The alien suit meant Spider-Man no longer required webshooters or cartridges to produce webbing.  It also provided Spider-Man with some special abilities that allowed him to travel through space and use his powers.

Comment: Spider-Man's cosmic powers had nothing to do with the alien symbiote/black costume.The short period of time when he had cosmic powers were due to the Captain Universe force, prepping him for a major threat to Earth.